# Got these notification, when I do the command "sudo nautilus"

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

```
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:4215): WARNING **: 15:05:10.895: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:4215): WARNING **: 15:05:10.895: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Nautilus-Share-Message: 15:05:10.997: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are playing with fire, running your graphical file manager as root user. Don't. You can break your system. If you use the file manager like it is supposed to be used, i.e., as normal user, then you will not have such warnings, you will have no need to fix them, and you will enjoy a stable system for your daily work.

The supported way to perform file manipulations as root is to open the file manager with the "admin:///" URL, as in

```
nautilus admin:///
```

You need to provide your login password. The first time during the session, the password is asked twice in a row.

Comment: I just want to change the icon theme on my Ubuntu, nothing more.
I followed the tutorial on Youtube, where one way is to do the command "sudo nautilus"

Comment: `sudo` should not be used with graphical programs, and modern trend is to move fully away from running any graphical interface as root. Using `nautilus admin:///` is supported, but has its limitations. If for your user only, you can change icon theme without being administrator.

Comment: OK, how do I change the icon theme without becoming an admin? can you give me the steps?

Comment: `nautilus admin:///` allows to perform file operations as root.

Comment: Thank you friends, I want to ask one more question, does copying files to root take a long time?
https://imgur.com/a/jGcj3lJ

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question here. Comments here are only meant to improve questions and answers and may disappear any time.